# Shell pattern matching - 2 files type, 1 exempt file type

Tags: shell, pattern-matching

I'm trying to find a shell pattern match that will match both...

`/x1234001a.20_` and `/x123001a.20.ext`

but not

`/x123001a.20.ext.A` or `/x123001a.20.A`

What I have tried...

`????????.??[_.]*[!A]` - finds only .ext file

`????????.??[_.]*[^A]` - does not find either

`????????.??[_.]*[ ext]` - does not find either

`????????.??[_.]*` - finds both, but also finds .A files

It needs to be just the path that is capable of matching, no extra commands, no extglob shell option, and no regex

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Maybe `^/[[:alnum:]]+\.[0-9]+(_|\.ext)$` [*regex*](https://regex101.com/r/skgjCj/1) will do?

Comment: Sorry, edited to add no regex either!

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer!

`????????.??*[!A]`

Comment: Still not sure why my previous version [_.]*[!A] does not work if anyone has an explanation. I assuming it has to do with it thinking there is another character after the *